# Postgres auto-vacuum doesn't reclaim the dead tuples space causes disk full issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, autovacuum

I have a use case to insert 100 000 rows per min at the same time in another end few threads will take the rows and delete them from my table. So definitely it will create lot of dead tuples in my table.

My auto-vacuum configurations are

```
autovacuum_max_workers = 3
autovacuum_naptime = 1min
utovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

From "pg_stat_user_tables" I can find auto-vacuum is running on my table but within a few hours my disk will be full (500 GB) and I can't able to insert any new row.

on the second try, I changed the following configuration

```
autovacuum_naptime = 60min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
```

This time my simulation and auto-vacuum are running well and max disk size is 180 GB.

Here my doubt is, if I change the "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay" to zero ms, how auto-vacuum freeing the dead tuples space and PG reuse it? why it is not working as intended if I set the value is 20 ms?

Comment: What do you mean by "1 lack rows per min"? Are you inserting and deleting only 1 row per minute? How big are the rows?

Comment: Besides, if you're having such trouble then you should decrease the naptime and not increase it to 60 minutes.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson I think he meant lakh, or 100,000 rows.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: Thanks @jjanes - I had no idea about that word

Answer (score 2):

> Here my doubt is, if I change the "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay" to zero ms, how auto-vacuum freeing the dead tuples space and PG reuse it?

The space freed up by vacuum is recorded in the [free space map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/storage-fsm.html), from where it gets handed out for re-use by future INSERTs.

Another detail to add, in 9.6 the free space map is only vacuumed once the entire table itself is completely vacuumed, and so the freed up space is not findable until then.  If the VACUUM never makes it to the very end, because it is too slow or gets interupted, then the space it is freeing up will not be reused for INSERTs.  This was improved in v11.

> why it is not working as intended if I set the value is 20 ms?

Because vacuum can't keep up at that value.  The default values for PostgreSQL are often suitable only for smaller servers, which yours doesn't seem to be.  It is appropriate and advisable to change the defaults in this situation.  Note that in v12, the default was lowered from 20 to 2 (and its type was correspondingly changed from int to float, so you can now specify the value with more precision)

Comment: Thank you @jjanes ...  have one more doubt on auto vacuum..just assume if one auto vacuum thread is running on my table before it completes its task, if another auto vacuum thread is coming and clean the same table then what will happen for the first thread? The first thread will be halt or interrupted or just break his work?

Comment: The 2nd one will just skip the table.  The first one will continue.

Comment: If it is working like that, at one point of time the first thread should complete his vacuum task and free up space right?  unless the first thread got any exception?

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, your app creates tons of dead tuples and autovacuum can't keep up. Possible solutions

1. This sounds more like a task queue than a regular table. Perhaps a PostgreSQL table is not ideal for your this specific use case. Use a solution such as RabbitMQ/Redis instead.
2. Create time-based range partitions and purge old partitions once they're empty, while disabling autovacuum on this table alone. Consider not deleting rows at all and just purging old partitions if you can identify handled partitions.
3. Tweak with the autovacuum settings so that it works constantly, without any naps or interference. Increasing `maintenance_work_mem` could help speed autovacuum too. Perhaps you'll find out that you've reached your hard-drive's limits. In that case, you will have to optimize the storage so that it can accommodate those expensive `INSERT`+`DELETE`+`autovacuum` operations.

Comment: Thank you, @Jonathan Jacobson. I don't have much knowledge about RabbitMQ... But Regarding the Redis, it will not suitable for our use case because each row size will be 0.1Mb size for my use-case. Since Redis uses RAM so it will be very costlier to store that much amount of data in Redis but anyways we are going to delete the data still if any error occurs on deleting threads, the component should hold the data at least for few hours, right?

Comment: @Mideenabdulgaffoor Create a partition per hour, and purge old partitions on a regular basis. 0 deleted tuples. 0 work for autovacuum.

Answer (score 0):

Well the default value is `2 ms` [Autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html). So your `20ms` value is high:

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay (floating point)

"Specifies the cost delay value that will be used in automatic VACUUM operations. If -1 is specified, the regular vacuum_cost_delay value will be used. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as milliseconds. The default value is 2 milliseconds. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line; but the setting can be overridden for individual tables by changing table storage parameters."

As explained here [Vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-VACUUM-COST-DELAY):

"
vacuum_cost_delay (floating point)

The amount of time that the process will sleep when the cost limit has been exceeded. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as milliseconds. The default value is zero, which disables the cost-based vacuum delay feature. Positive values enable cost-based vacuuming.

When using cost-based vacuuming, appropriate values for vacuum_cost_delay are usually quite small, perhaps less than 1 millisecond. While vacuum_cost_delay can be set to fractional-millisecond values, such delays may not be measured accurately on older platforms. On such platforms, increasing VACUUM's throttled resource consumption above what you get at 1ms will require changing the other vacuum cost parameters. You should, nonetheless, keep vacuum_cost_delay as small as your platform will consistently measure; large delays are not helpful.
"

Comment: The default for `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` was 20ms back in 9.6 which is what the OP is using.